# Examples of interesting semantics to study during a small project for a graduate Semantics course

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, operational-semantics

I have been following the course Concrete Semantics with Isabelle/HOL. At some point we are given the task to verify a program/extend some semantic construction/prove some mathematical fact. I personally prefer to dive a little bit more into operational semantics, so adding new features to the IMP language is the way to go.

The classical extensions are non-determinism/parallel execution. These are described in a variety of books (Winskel, Hennessy or Nielson to cite only classical authors). However, I feel the treatment is rather limited and I'm not sure that can be turned into project, it looks more like a bunch of exercises.

So my question is  are you aware of any simple but interesting extensions of the operational semantics approach to the study of a simple WHILE-program (such as IMP)? I would be looking specially for significant properties that can be proved in that semantics and illustrative examples that may be relevant.

Comment: This question is a bit broad for CS.SE. Here we prefer questions having a definite answer. Still, it shows some effort, so I'm not going to vote-close it (but I wouldn't be surprised if others are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add more flow control to IMP, like (simple) exceptions, or `break` to exit early from a `while` loop.

You could some partial operators (division, square root) requiring you to handle runtime errors.

You could add more complex data types, like pairs. Make it so that e.g. projecting a value out of a non-pair value causes a runtime error. Craft a (first-order) simple type system e.g. using `T ::= int | (T*T)` as types, and prove that "typeable programs do not go wrong", i.e. executing them never lead to runtime errors.

You could add functions / procedures. This is not so trivial at first, especially if you want to consider several ways for parameter passing (e.g. pass-by-value, pass-by-reference).

You could prove that a suitable restriction of IMP (say, sans `while`, or with a constrained `while`) is always terminating.